# Can't obtain google maps api key

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I obtained fingerprint and put it into corresponding form at http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html, but when I pressed "Generate API key", I saw no key, it looks like that:

[image]

No key, only question marks. Did anyone encounter this problem? I tried to change encoding and use another browser but always got the same result. What's the matter?

Comment: Have you tried other browsers?

Answer (score 2):

That page would have given you an old-style API key that would only work with deprecated APIs, so just forget about it.

Instead, use the [API Console](http://code.google.com/apis/console) to create a key under API Access. See [Obtaining an API Key](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html#api_key) for details.